# Formatting string connected to for loop from a list (python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, format

I want to display a single string connected to values from a list displayed using a for loop

For example I have this:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
print("Numbers: ")
for i in nums:
    print(i)
```

but I would like it to be displayed with the 1 starting after "Numbers:"

e.g

Numbers: 1
2
3
...

How would I format the code to enable this to happen?

Comment: how about this - `print("Numbers:", "\n".join(map(str, nums)))`

Answer (score 0):

Pass `end=''` to `print()`:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
print("Numbers: ", end='')
for i in nums:
    print(i)
```